# Scrolling up one line in bash, when opened via the PyCharm IDE

Tags: bash, scroll, pycharm, hotkeys

PyCharm offers the option to use the bash terminal (see File->Setting, where this screen comes up:)

[image]

Now when I have the bash terminal open while coding in PyCharm, like so

[image]

and want to scroll up line by line with the keyboard (in this case to view line by line the output of the previous command, pytest, that I ran that output the error message), I can't, no combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Sift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd> will work (only <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> scrolls up - but by a whole page, not a line, which is too much).

I'm not sure, is this because of bash or because of Pycharm (I'm using Ubuntu (16.04), if that matters).

This issue is really driving me nuts!